# How can I see my old answer(s), to improve them?

Tags: discussion, old-answers

I have barely answered one question in these columns. But, since yesterday I am not allowed to answer any, as the filter has decided my earlier answers (sic!) were of poor quality. I am also suggested that I should try to improve my existing answers, among other things, to get the ban lifted. While I have strong reasons to feel that this filter appears to be a coffee filter with no holes in the top compartment, isn't it fair on my part to get a link that would take me to my earlier answers (sic again, as the plural term 'answers' is irrelevant since I had answered only once).

Comment: This is probably a question for meta. If you had answers in the 57 days that you have been a member I suspect they were all deleted. I can't tell because I do not have enough reputation to see deleted answers.

Comment: its probably a coffee filter

Comment: All I see is a rejected edit suggestion; no answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see your recently deleted answers on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/6380992).

You can edit your answers linked there, then comment here (since you can't flag yet). Note that I'm not going to undelete answers that should still be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

All the questions that you have asked are there in your profile, you can visit them and edit them if you wish to.

Comment: But keep in mind that deleted question and answers can only be found there for 60 days after posting. After that period you have to wait till you're 10K

Comment: If there are three answers so far, out of which one is a comment that should not have been posted as I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, I have practically nil probability to 'improve' them before expiry. Would this in turn mean that I would never be able to answer any query?